# \label inside \caption throws an error. If after the \caption, references to it point to the section instead of the figure number

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, labels, tufte, ref

I am using the `tufte-book` document class to compose a document in Overleaf.

I was getting an issue where when I referenced figures. Instead of `\ref{}` giving me the number for the figure itself, it gave me the number of the section the figure was in. This question has popped up here before, but the solution typically given --- “place the `\label` **after** the `\caption`” --- produces no change for me.

What did work is to put the `\label` inside the `\caption`, as in the following example:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{img.eps}
  \caption{\label{fig:myimg}Example caption}
\end{figure}
```

This fixes the `\ref` problem, but Overleaf gives me an error message (although it compiles the PDF normally):

[image: Undefined control sequence. Argument of @iiminipage has an extra}. Runaway argument?]

> Image label: Undefined control sequence. Argument of @iiminipage has an extra}. Runaway argument?

Here is a MWE. I run it on Overleaf with XeLaTeX.

**Imporant note**: I'm importing the `subfigure` package. I'm not using it here, but I use it on my actual document, and I've found that removing it fixes the issue! So it must be what's causing the issue, but why?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{subfigure} 

% add numbers to chapters, sections, subsections, subsubsections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}


Hello world.

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

See figure~\ref{fig:my_label}?

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{helix.pdf}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Output from the code above. It is a dummy document with some sections and an image.]

Comment: please make a small but complete document that produces the error so people can debug, also show the actual error from the log, as a text code block, not just a screenshot of the summary, the error message will show _which_ command is undefined.

Comment: Done! In doing so I've managed to narrow the issue to the subfigure package (which I need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the `subfigure` package with the `subfig` package fixed both issues!

Not only can I keep labels inside captions (e.g., `\caption{\label{fig:myimg}Example caption}`) as I was doing with no Overleaf error message, I can also leave them after the `\caption` and the `\ref` works (e.g., `\caption{Example caption}\label{fig:myimg}`).